# My rigging deforms the body of the character and moves random parts. What did I do wrong? What do I do to fix it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

I'm new to rigging and this is my first major project with it. The goal is to rig my "transformer" body well. However, I'm running into issues with the posing as random parts of the mesh move.

At (0,0,0) is my rigged object. And to its left is an individual part-based object for reference.

[image: Hand dislocated just by entering pose mode]
Hand dislocated just by entering pose mode.

[image: When moving body parts the body just dislocates]
When moving body parts the body just dislocates.

Blend File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nWkBXivnpbU5tIriuGBp0Phm_3gR0hBj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i didn't check more, but your face orientation of your robot is wrong. If fixing that doesn't help, pls upload again [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4j8d.png

Comment: Hello, could you please tell what part is moving wrongly? Maybe show a screenshot

Comment: There's a comprehesive multipart tutorial series about rigging a robot simiar to yours [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKvJKV5fiIU&list=PLbjn7kaP877v6ByHd-fgek3kOmUYFOzR0&pp=iAQB). It uses Blender 2.8 but the workflow is the same in later versions.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @chris how do I fix that?

Comment: go in edit mode -> A -> shift-N

Answer (score 0):

As Chris says, first thing, recalculate the normals in *Edit* mode (select all and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>). For the parts that don't work, select them in *Edit* mode, remove them from all groups:

[image]

Then manually assign to the correct vertex group:

[image]